# Appcelerator Studio: Cannot create a new project

Tags: model-view-controller, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I'm experiencing problems with Appcelerator Studio.
If I try to make a new project inside the workspace, I receive the following error:
"Error while reading/writing the .project file"

I tried to write outside the workspace. It doesn't create a Hello World project! Instead I have an empty project with only 3 files: CHANGELOG, LICENSE, manifest. Unable to add new models, views or controllers: the New command does nothing.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to create a new project via command line (appc new). I receive the following messages: ""create" is an unrecognized command." "ERROR  | titanium exited with non-zero exit code (1)"

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reinstall Appcelerator Studio and make sure that you installed all the required tools.

Also try to update Appcelerator CLI tool.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I tried to reinstall Appcelerator Studio more than 2 times. I tried to reinstall nodejs, titanium cli and sdk. Currently it shows lots of strange errors in log file. Currently I'm using CLI and Atom as IDE.

Comment: which nodejs version you installed?

Comment: The last stable version 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I find entering:
appc logout
appc login

Fixes a lot of problems.  That being said I did have to uninstall/reinstall studio a couple of weeks ago as it wouldn't start up. I have also had goofy issues once when installed a node.js version above what was supported.